# increase selection outline width in QGraphicsTextitem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

i have a QGraphicsTextitem with text interaction where user can edit the current text and add the new text . but my new requirement is to increase the selection outline width and can be controlled by a QSlider. is it possible to increase the dotted selection width of the QGraphicsTextItem.
i wanted to increase the pen thickness or size of the selection box coming around the text ..[image]

in the image a dotted lines bound the text . is it possible to increase the dotted line pen size or thickness.

Comment: The selection width should automatically resize according to text size.

Comment: sorry for not clear with my question .. actually im asking about the pen width or the frame thickness ..i added more clear description in my question again ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is ancient, but I'll do my civic duty to try an answer:

There are a few things you must do.

1. Subclass your `QGraphicsTextItem`
2. Override the `paint` method, and inside it remove the default selection style, and draw your own

---

```
void TextItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem opt(*option);

    // Remove the selection style state, to prevent the dotted line from being drawn.
    opt.state = QStyle::State_None;

    // Draw your fill on the item rectangle (or as big as you require) before drawing the text
    // This is where you can use your calculated values (as member variables) from what you did with the slider
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::green);
    painter->drawRect(whateverRectangle());

    // Call the parent to do the actual text drawing 
    QGraphicsTextItem::paint(painter, &opt, widget);

    // You can use these to decide when you draw
    bool textEditingMode = (textInteractionFlags() & Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    bool isSelected = (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected);

    // Draw your rectangle - can be different in selected mode or editing mode if you wish

    if (option->state & (QStyle::State_Selected))
    {
        // You can change pen thickness for the selection outline if you like
        painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DotLine)); 
        painter->setBrush(Qt::magenta);
        painter->drawRect(whateverRectangle());
    }
}
```

---

3. You may have to override the `boundingRect`, `opaqueArea` and `shape` functions to account for your increased size.